# View details from object as a community User

Tags: opportunity, security, portal

I have a script on our website that shows the details of an object by putting his primary key in a text field. It works fine when I open the website from salesforce as a preview : 
[image]

When I go on a live version of the portal it filters out some information as such:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone has any solutions to this, I went to this profile and put every object related as read all except I couldn't find the opportunity object.The fields that are missing are :

- Opportunity__r.Name
- Service_Start_Date__c
- Opportunity__r.Works_CSP__c
- Opportunity__r.Name
- Local_Service__r.name

[image]

Comment: That screenshot is the Public portal profile?

Comment: Yes that's a public portal profile.

Comment: Are you just asking how to make those fields visible?

Comment: Well, Yes how to display those fields when executing this script as a Community/Portal User

Comment: Did you check the Sharing Settings in the Setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Opportunity Object isn't available to customer community users for create, edit, read or delete. See [Communities User Licenses](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) for more on what objects are exposed depending on which license you choose. The only way you could expose the specific fields would be to mirror them to a custom object and share the custom object. In doing so, I need to caution you that you might be violating your TOS with Salesforce.

Comment: Service Instance is a custom object and that's where the Opportunity Name is mirrored, unless I cant use Master-detail relationship for mirroring .Do you know what could be the reason for the Service Start date or Local Service to not show ?

Comment: You're correct that you don't want to use a M-D relationship for mirroring. Security on a child object is controlled by the parent.

Comment: i've set up those 3 custom fields created 3 workflows to populate and used them in the SOQL inside of apex. IT works great now thank you

Answer (score 0):

- You can also map the field values to Wrapper class variables and
  render the wrapper class instance.
- But as mentioned in other answers, in doing
  so, I am not sure if you might be violating your TOS with Salesforce.